# 3 table mysql join working, but taking too long

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables:

> 1. districts | id, zipcode, district
> 2. subscription | id, userid, status, level
> 3. profile | id, userid, zip

I am trying to count the amount of zip codes from active subscriptions and group them by district.  ( I am using LEFT() so I can can include zips in the #####-#### format).  The query works in 6.4 seconds locally, but on the server isn't outputting in a timely manner.  What can I do to speed this up?

I have written:

```
SELECT COUNT( d.zipcode ) total, d.district
FROM districts AS d
JOIN profile AS p ON d.zipcode = LEFT(p.zip, 5)
JOIN subscriptions AS s ON s.userid = p.userid
WHERE s.status = 1
GROUP BY d.district
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an index on:
d.zipcode
p.zip
s.userid
p.userid
s.status

Comment: Thanks Dweeves,  haven't ever used indexing, so I will give that a go!!

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're using a function in your join. Therefore no index can be used. Why do you save zip in table profile? Save the districts.id in profile instead of zip, that would make sense.

EDIT: Actually you shouldn't do overindexing like Dweeves suggests. But you should add a foreign key to profile referencing districts.

```
ALTER TABLE profile ADD CONSTRAINT fk_zip_districts FOREIGN KEY (districtsId) REFERENCING districts(id);
```

assuming that you do like I said above.

```
profile | id, userId, districtsId
```

Comment: Probably need both zipcode and districts_id, but putting it in the profile is a great idea. Want to show the OP what that query would look like?

Comment: Occasionally a zip code will move to a different district, for a variety of reason, so I didn't want to store the district number in the profile.  I thought it would be easier to reference it from the districts table.  The report I am generating from this query is the only thing we use the district for.

Comment: So? Don't see a problem here. Or do you want to know to which district a zip code belonged when the profile was created? I guess no. The zip code moves to another district? Then update your districts table and the profile is in the actual district, no matter where the zip was in the past. You want to have up to date data, right?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter to which district they were upon registration.  Only currently.  I will update it how you suggested it.  In the ALTER statement above, should "REFERENCING" be "REFERENCES"?

Comment: oh, yes, my fault, I sometimes mix MySQL and SQL Server :)

Comment: I hear ya.  Doesn't it just want to make you sometimes mix tequila and lime juice :)

Comment: @Munk Hm, friday evening... :) ok, glad I could help you. Feel free to accept my answer as useful :)

Comment: Thanks tombom.  I would, but I don't have enough reputation to at this point!!

Comment: ? I mean the green arrow to the left of my answer. That should be possible everytime.